# Why the output of this code is different?

Tags: java

```
int a[] = {120, 50, 016};

for(int P : a)
    System.out.print(P+" ");
```

I expect the output of above code is 120 50 16, but the actual output is 120 50 14.

Comment: `016` is 14 in radix 8

Comment: The leading 0 stands for octal numeral system: In this your 016 =  1  * (8^1) + 6 * (8^0)  = 14

Comment: have a look at Java Language Specification [3.10. Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) - some more *strange* (good to know) facts, like underscore in literal numbers

Answer (score 0):

That is because '016' is behaving as and its octal value 14.

Answer (score 0):

It is octal base 8 because you have a 0 in front.

See the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal